# bookmark / Favorite page using query firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want user to retrieve favorite by using query from firestore.

My approach is to use Bool within firestore and then connect to

```
class Food {

  String id;
  String name;
  String category;
  String newcategory;
  String image;
  List subIngredients = [];
  Timestamp createdAt;
  Timestamp updatedAt;
  bool isFavourite;

  Food();
//  Food(this.id, this.name, this.category, this.newcategory, this.image, this.subIngredients, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt);

  Food.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    this.id = data['id'];
    this.name = data['name'];
    this.category = data['category'];
    this.newcategory = data['newcategory'];
    this.image = data['image'];
    this.subIngredients = data['subIngredients'];
    this.createdAt = data['create at'];
    this.updatedAt = data['updatedAt'];
    this.isFavourite = data['isFavourite'];
    
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': this.id,
      'name': this.name,
      'category': this.category,
      'newcategory': this.newcategory,
      'image': this.image,
      'subIngredients': this.subIngredients,
      'create at': this.createdAt,
      'updatedAt': this.updatedAt,
      'isFavourite': this.isFavourite,
    };
  }

}
```

I placed an onsaved button, but I can not figure out the proper way to have the button on product page which will save or bookmark into

```
final _saved = Set<BuildContext>(
    
  );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      final alreadySaved =  _saved.contains(context);

                    new IconButton(
                    icon: alreadySaved ? Icon(Icons.star) : Icon(Icons.star_border),
                    color: alreadySaved ? Colors.yellow[500] : null,
                    onPressed:  (){
                      setState(() {
                      if (alreadySaved) {
                        _saved.remove(context);
                        } else {
                        _saved.add(context); 
                        }
                      });}
                    )
```

I started to build a query as per below in which I will include bool with if isFavorite= true

```
getFavorites(FoodNotifier foodNotifier) async {
    DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Foods')
        .document(user.uid)
        .get();

    if (querySnapshot.exists &&
        querySnapshot.data.containsKey('favorites') &&
        querySnapshot.data['favorites'] is List) {
      // Create a new List<String> from List<dynamic>
      return List<Food>.from(querySnapshot.data['favorites']);
    }
    return [];
  }
```

So far I am failing to create the database with bool and select per user and favorite.

```
 final _saved = Set<BuildContext>(
    
  );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      final alreadySaved =  _saved.contains(context);

    FoodNotifier foodNotifier = Provider.of<FoodNotifier>(context);
    
    
    _onFoodDeleted(Food food) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      foodNotifier.deleteFood(food);
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(foodNotifier.currentFood.name),
        actions: <Widget>[
                    Text('add to Favorite'),
          // action button
                    new IconButton(
                    icon: alreadySaved ? Icon(Icons.star) : Icon(Icons.star_border),
                    color: alreadySaved ? Colors.yellow[500] : null,
                    onPressed:  (){
                      setState(() {
                      if (alreadySaved) {
                        _saved.remove(context);
                        } else {
                        _saved.add(context); 
                        }
                      });}
                    )
                    ]
```

Comment: Are you trying to create structure in Firestore or you have one and you try to create a query? If you have can you share the structure?

Comment: Hi vitooh, the query is working in firestore. But to move and retrieve only favorite from user is where I am blocked. I haved added some of my codes related to query,